# Twitter Bootstrap Popover - DOM Insertion Location

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have Bootstrap Popovers working fine, but the popover get's appended to **body** at the bottom of the document, as opposed to just below the triggering element, as it does in the bootstrap documentation: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Anyone know how to control where a popover is inserted?  Or at the very least, get it to append to the triggering elements parent?

Here's what I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/qt34N/4/

```
 <a href="#" class="btn" rel="popover" data-placement="top" 
  data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." 
  data-original-title="Popover on top">Popover on top</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover();
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What is the reason for having it append at a certain location? It's usually better to code around the framework/library than modify the framework/library when possible.

Comment: Yes, I'd rather not modify the framework/library at all.  I'm saying I'm getting a different result then the bootstrap documentation demos are giving, which are placing the popover right below the clicked element.  In all my attempts, the popover gets placed at the bottom of <body>.  Know why?  I'm using the latest versions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo is using a newer version of bootstrap. Update to the latest and it will perform like you want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/qt34N/10/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a[rel=popover]").popover();
});​
```

Comment: Yep, I was using version 2.1.1, when I upgraded to 2.2.1, the popovers were placed right after the clicked element.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using bootstrap v 4.1 but still it appends the popover content just before the body end tag. I've the popover button in tr td and I want the popover content on the same place. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know anything about bootstrap 4x

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the tooltip (bootstrap-tooltip.js) as required?
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

> Add small overlays of content, like those on the iPad, to any element for housing secondary information. Hover over the button to trigger the popover. **Requires Tooltip to be included**.

As far as placement goes, you set it in the options:

```
$('#example').popover({placement:'top'})
```

or via `data` attribute:

```
data-placement="top"
```

Comment: Yes, I am loading the entire bootstrap.min.js, which loads all the plugins, including bootstrap-tooltip.js...  And yes, the placement option works for me both ways, but only affects the physical appearance placement, not it's placement in the dom.