# Make bootstrap popover appear under mouse

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am attempting to make a popover appear under the mouse cursor when the user hovers over text in a certain element using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2. Because the text being hovered over is not a link I cannot get the popover to place itself appropriately and end up with the popover appearing around the parent element, and not the text.

In order to get around this problem I would like to have the popover just appear under the mouse cursor.

I tried the answer given in this question [bootstrap popover, how to make it appear on the place where my mouse move on?(not only top/bottom/right/left)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743076/bootstrap-popover-how-to-make-it-appear-on-the-place-where-my-mouse-move-onno?lq=1), however it appears that an event is never made so it isn't possible to get the coordinates.

For reference I am currently just calling the popover like this:

```
$('#content').popover(placement: 'mouse', html: true, title: 'test', 
  content: 'TESTING').popover('show')
```

error when using the linked questions solution:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
```

To help explain the process up, The user hovers over regular text that has a a hover EventListener attached to it. I then want to open up a popover under the mouse cursor with information from an ajax request that is initiated after the hover.

Is there any way to do this? The popover seems very attached to using links and the linked question was the only lead I had.